# Why does not get evaluate?

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet:

```
*Main Lib> let myList = [1, 2, id 1] :: [Integer]
*Main Lib> let myList' = myList ++ undefined
*Main Lib> :sprint myList'
myList' = _
```

Why does the `myList` does not get evaluated?

And this too:

```
*Main Lib> x = 45
*Main Lib> :sprint x
x = _
```

Comment: Because nothing is evaluated unless it absolutely has to in Haskell?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602657/67579)

Comment: Why do you think it should get evaluated?

Comment: @augustss: I think the OP means that `x = 45` has not much to evaluate. But because `ghci` uses the `MonomorphismRestriction`, it does not pick a type for `x` (so no `Int`, `Integer`, etc.)

Comment: Let's consider the first example. When I write `*Main Lib> myList ++ undefined` then it is an application and it gets evaluated. When I write `let myList' = myList ++ undefined` is a lambda abstraction, that why it does not get evaluated, right?

Comment: Because if you write `myList ++ undefined`, you have implicitly written `print (myList ++ undefined)`. So you force Haskell to generate textual output, and this requires some evaluation.

Comment: and what about ` myList'`?

Comment: a `let` statement is never evaluated eagerly. Only if it needs to be, like anything in Haskell.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the link.