# What does "s" mean in the "sprint" GHCi command?

Tags: haskell, ghci

What does "s" mean in the name of the `:sprint` GHCi command?
This is [the description from the official documentation](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:sprint), to give you some context:

> sprint :  Prints a value without forcing its evaluation. :sprint is similar to :print, with the difference that unevaluated subterms are not bound to new variables, they are simply denoted by ‘_’.

Comment: could it be 's' for strictness ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have seen, the description of `:sprint` in the GHC User's Guide says nothing on the matter. According to the [`:sprint` entry](https://typeclasses.com/ghci/sprint) in Julie Moronuki and Chris Martin's typeclasses.com...

> The `s` stands for “simple,” the idea being that `:sprint` is in some sense a simplified version of the `:print` command, since `:sprint` does less work.

---

> could it be 's' for strictness ?

Presumably not, as much of the point of `:sprint` and `:print` is that they are, in a sense, [lazier than the `print` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198306/why-sprint-always-prints-a).

Answer (score 1):

1. type `ghci`
2. type `:?`
3. You will get: `Commands available from the prompt:`
4. Look for the `sprintf:` documentation

   `:sprint [<name> ...]        simplified version of :print`