# :sprint var is printing _ even after being evaluated

Tags: haskell, ghci

I read [Why :sprint always prints a "_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198306/why-sprint-always-prints-a) but I seem to be encountering something else.

```
ghci> sum = foldl (+) 0
ghci> let total = sum [1..1000000]
ghci> :sprint total
total = _ -- This is expected due to lazy eval
ghci> print total
500000500000
ghci> :sprint total
total = _ -- This is NOT expected since total has been evaluated.
ghci> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction -- recommended by one of the other answers.
ghci> :sprint total
total = _
ghci> print total
50000005000000
ghci> :sprint total
total = _
ghci> :sprint sum
sum = _
ghci> ints = [1..5]
ghci> :sprint ints
ints = _
ghci> print ints
[1,2,3,4,5]
ghci> :sprint ints
ints = [1,2,3,4,5] -- Yay!
```

Useful info:

```
ghci> :show
options currently set: none.
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
GHCi-specific dynamic flag settings:
other dynamic, non-language, flag settings:
  -fexternal-dynamic-refs
  -fignore-optim-changes
  -fignore-hpc-changes
  -fimplicit-import-qualified
warning settings:
```

and

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.0.2
```

So the question then is: why and what can I do to "fix" this? I'm reading along with https://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `total` after enabling `MonomorphismRestriction` extension.

```
ghci> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction 
ghci> sum = foldl (+) 0
ghci> let total = sum [1..1000000]
ghci> :sprint total
total = _
ghci> print total
500000500000
ghci> :sprint total
total = 500000500000
```

Or you can give a specific type to `total` (without `MonomorphismRestriction` extension).

```
ghci> sum = foldl (+) 0
ghci> let total = sum [1..1000000] :: Int
ghci> :sprint total
total = _
ghci> print total
500000500000
ghci> :sprint total
total = 500000500000
```

The thing is, under `NoMonomorphismRestriction` (the default), the type of `total` will be `(Num a, Enum a) => a`. GHCi evaluates it every time if the type of a value is polymorphic like this. So `:sprintf` cannot print the evaluated value.

When you give it a specific type, `:sprintf` can print the evaluated value. Note that the type of `total` will become `Integer` with `MonomorphismRestriction`.